Why when i send a fecth requst to Open Weather API in React JS. React first return me undefined an after that data?
I watn to make Weather App. I just start study react. I do a fetch request to Open Weather API to get a weather data. When i consol.log(data) and update my page, React first return me undefined and after that data. I can't use data in other components because data is undefined.
App.jsx
function App() {
    const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState()
    useEffect(()=>{
        requestWeather('London')
    }, [])
    let requestWeather = async (city)=> {
        try {
            const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=4e4ff6f3165d9a027265ab73068e5a3a&mode=JSON`
            fetch(url)
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(data => {
                setWeatherData(data)
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    console.log(weatherData);
    return (
        <>
            <div className="wrapper">
                <Weather weather_data={weatherData}/>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

Weather.jsx
export default function Weather({weather_data}){
    return(
        <div>{weather_data.name}</div>
        // There '.name' display name of city

    )
}

When i run that i got this errors
ERRORS

In the updated question, the (picture of) errors shown don't seem to match the changes that have been made to the code.  (As an aside, I also disagree with the chosen duplicate.  This question isn't returning from an asynchronous operation.  Aside from the unnecessary use of async on that function, the asynchronous code is correct.)

No default value was specified for the state:
const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState();

So it defaults to undefined.  You could add any default you like.  For example, this would default to an empty object:
const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState({});

Or you could not render the Weather component if the value is "falsy":
<div className="wrapper">
  { weatherData ? <Weather weather_data={weatherData}/> : null }
</div>

Or you could handle undefined within the Weather component itself:
<div>{weather_data?.name}</div>


Unrelated, but you'll also want to get in the habit of terminating statements with semi-colons.  JavaScript is forgiving about omitting semi-colons, but programmers should not be.  It's one of those things that will work just fine right up until the moment it doesn't.

How can i combine {data ?  : null} and  .map(). Example: i have a array with objects.I want do .map() for array and send each object.key to Item and display it as many times as there are elements in the array?

@HelpMeStudy: What stops you from using .map() on your array?  If you’ve made some attempt to do something and it doesn’t work in some specific way then that probably merits posting a Stack Overflow question.

When your component renders it makes an api call to obtain the weather, so untill your call successfully retrieves the weather data and sets it in the state, your weatherData is undefined.
The solution David provided is also valid.
My proposal would be to not render your Weather component untill the data is successfully loaded and saved to state like so:
function App() {
    const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState();
    const [isWeatherDataLoading, setIsWeatherDataLoading] = useState(true);
    const [weatherLoadingError, setWeatherLoadingError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        requestWeather("London");
    }, []);

    const requestWeather = (city) => {
        setIsWeatherDataLoading(true);
        setWeatherLoadingError(null);

        const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=4e4ff6f3165d9a027265ab73068e5a3a&mode=JSON`;
        fetch(url)
            .then((data) => data.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setWeatherData(data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                setWeatherLoadingError(JSON.stringify(error));
            })
            .finally(() => {
                setIsWeatherDataLoading(false);
            });
    };

    if (isWeatherDataLoading) {
        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div>Loading weather</div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    if (weatherLoadingError) {
        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div>Failed to load weather data with error: {weatherLoadingError}</div>
                <button onClick={() => requestWeather("London")}>Try again</button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <Weather weather_data={weatherData} />
        </div>
    );
}


In a similar fashion:
Unrelated, but you'll also want to get in the habit of handling loading and error states in your React apps. The interviewer might be forgiving, but the user story should not be.
